# How to use widget.switch to change editText values Android

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I have a widget.switch and I'm trying to have it divide particular numbers by two (or multiply them by two) depending on the value of the switch.

Here's essentially what I have, edited for privacy:

in the onCreate:

```
theSwtch = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.theSwtch);
theSwtch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (theSwtch.isChecked()){theSwtch.setText("Weekly"); switcher = true;}
        else if (!theSwtch.isChecked()){theSwtch.setText("Bi-Weekly"); switcher = false;}
        // do something, the isChecked will be
        // true if the switch is in the On position
    }
});
```

and in the OnClick:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Double someNumber = Double.parseDouble(editTextInput.getText().toString());
    if (view.getId() == theSwitch.getId()){
        if (!theSwitch.isChecked()) {
            someNumber = someNumber/2;
            editTextInput.setText(someNumber.toString());
        } else if (wklySwtch.isChecked()) {
            someNumber = someNumber*2;
            editTextInput.setText(someNumber.toString());
        }
        if (view.getId() == btnCalculate.getId()) {
            outPut.setText(someNumber.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your logic to divide or multiply from the OnClickListener, instead, do the whole thing in the OnCheckedChangedListener:

```
    theSwtch = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.theSwtch);
    theSwtch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Double someNumber = Double.parseDouble(editTextInput.getText().toString());
            if (theSwtch.isChecked()){
                theSwtch.setText("Weekly"); 
                switcher = true;
                someNumber = someNumber/2;
                editTextInput.setText(someNumber.toString());
            } else if (!theSwtch.isChecked()) {
                theSwtch.setText("Bi-Weekly"); 
                switcher = false;
                someNumber = someNumber*2;
                editTextInput.setText(someNumber.toString());
            }
                // do something, the isChecked will be
               // true if the switch is in the On position
        }
    });
```